# What is wrong with this statement echo '<option value='+$index+'>'+$county[$index];?

Tags: php, string

```
echo '<option value='+$index+'>'+$county[$index];
```

It is PHP code. It doesn't output what I want. Any idea?

Comment: If you have to ask a question this rudimentary you shouldn't be on StackOverflow, go read the first chapter of any PHP tutorial or website.

Comment: Travis: Maybe you should answer him and include links to appropriate PHP tutorials and websites.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To concatenate text in PHP use the `.` operator not the `+`

```
echo '<option value='.$index.'>'.$county[$index];
```

You can read more about the `.` and the `.=` operators if you want: [String Operators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
echo '<option value=' . $index . '>' . $county[$index];
```

You can even do this way too:

```
echo "<option value={$index}>{$county[$index]}";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use either:

```
echo '<option value=' . $index+'>' . $county[$index];
```

or

```
echo "<option value='$index'>$county[$index]";
```

Answer (score 0):

With the `echo` statement, unlike with other things in PHP, you can also use a `,` to concatenate. It's said to be faster than the `.`

```
echo '<option value=' , $index , '>' , $county[$index];
```

Comment: The comma (,) does not concatenate. Echo is a language-construct, which is why you don't (usually) use parentheses. It would be similar to using: echo($first, $second, $third). If you want to pass more than one parameter to echo, you must _not_ use the parentheses.

Comment: True, I guess I should've been more specific in that each part is really an argument you're giving echo rather than echo actually concatenating each part of the statement onto the end of the previous part. It does, however, achieve the same affect and faster

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '<option value="', $index, '">', $country[$index];
echo "<option value='$index'>$country[$index]";
printf('<option value="%s">%s', $index, $country[$index]);
```

There are other, additional ways (sprintf and echo, for one) that accomplish the same thing.
Take your pick.

Personally, I would use the first example, because [echo](http://php.net/echo) takes multiple arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the concatenation operator being `.`... PHP is a templating language. Use it, don't fight it! Avoid handling HTML in strings; let PHP itself do it.

And when you output arbitrary text, remember to HTML-escape it, to avoid cross-site-scripting problems. eg.:

```
<?php
    function h($s) {
        echo htmlspecialchars($s, ENT_QUOTES);
    }
?>
...

<select name="county">
    <?php for ($i= 0; $i<count($county); $i++) { ?>
        <option value="<?php h($i); ?>">
            <?php h($county[$i]); ?>
        </option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
```